# modifying parameters of an html page dynamically jquery

Tags: jquery, solrj

I have a function where I am obtaining results from a Solr index. The code is as follows:

```
AjaxSolr.theme.prototype.result = function (doc, snippet) {
 var figrhtmlocation=doc.imagelocation;
 var pdfl=doc.filelocation;
 var output = '<div> <h2>' + doc.caption+'</h2>';
 var figlink='<a href="" onclick="show_figure_html\('+'\''+figrl+'\''+'\)"> <p> See Figure </a>';
 var pdlink='<A href="'+pdfl+'"> \t See pdf </p> </A>';
 output+=figlink;
 output+=pdlink;
 output += '<p>' + snippet + '</p></div>';
 return output;
};
```

As you can see, I am creating a link with each result called "See Figure". Now, when I click that link, in my show_figure_html function I want to do following things:

1. Open an html page (say, figuredescription.html) in a new window or existing window.
2. The figuredescription.html page has a div element figuredisplay, where I want to dynamically append the figrlocation as the source of the image file. Something like appending the image location in the figuredescription.html div element.

How can I do that with jquery? I am pretty new to this, so forgive me if this question appears naive. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For opening  in a new window ,change your code to this

```
  var figlink='<a href="" target="_blank" onclick="show_figure_html\('+'\''+figrl+'\''+'\)"> <p> See Figure </a>';
```

and on your figuredescription.html, just add

```
$(function(){
  $(figuredisplay).html('your source for image ie figrlocation ')
})
```

here figuredisplay can be your class for your element or id for your element.
if class then use ('.figuredisplay ') and for id use ('#figuredisplay')

Comment: But I need to pass my figureloation from show_figure_html() function. How do I do that?